# WebSphere Liberty excessive startup time

Tags: startup, websphere-liberty

I'm trying to configure IBM WebSphere Liberty server (16.0.0.3) so that one of our applications runs there, but, besides the obvious unreliability, the server takes just to much time to start.
This is clear on the log files:

```
[17-11-2016 15:54:16:231 GMT] 0000001c com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.security.ServletStartedListener      I CWWKS9122I:  For URL /* in application com.ibm.ws.jmx.connector.server.rest, the following HTTP methods are uncovered, and accessible: HEAD OPTIONS TRACE 
[17-11-2016 15:56:18:349 GMT] 0000001b org.jboss.weld.Event                                         I WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.omnifaces.VetoAnnotatedTypeExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<T>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
[17-11-2016 15:56:19:798 GMT] 0000001b com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.osgi.internal.EJBRuntimeImpl         I CNTR4000I: The ALLPLEXEJBeans-v2.jar EJB module in the ECC application is starting.
```

As you can see, there are more than 2 minutes separating the first two lines, which is ridiculous, especially considering that it is a very small application.

What can I do to speed this up before giving up on Liberty profile?

Comment: See [article](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/cwlp_cdi_behavior.html) to see if you might want to run with `<cdi12 enableImplicitBeanArchives="false"/>` to short-circuit CDI scanning

Comment: does your app use CDI?

Comment: Hi Scott, that seemed to do the work, thanks. Do you want to put that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Alternatively, if you're not using CDI at all, you might consider removing it from `<featureManager>` (or whichever feature is pulling it in, such as `webProfile-7.0` or `javaee-7.0`).  All features add overhead, so the fewer required, the faster your server will start.

Comment: I didn't follow your comment "besides the obvious unreliability", were you commenting on Liberty's reliability or the non-deterministic startup time  prior to enabling the flag above?

Comment: I mentioned that because of all of the problems I'm having with it. With the help of some IBM engineers, a bug was detected and a fix will be included on the next release. When I start the server, sometimes my app starts automatically and some other times it doesn't and I've to do it manually (no errors). My datasource was working normally and, suddenly, it stopped working and I had to change it to XA datasource to make it work again... too many problems for just one server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CDI is a very useful, cross-cutting technology, but as part of that the CDI engine potentially needs to scan every single class in your application to see what is and isn't a CDI bean and to interpret other annotations, etc.

## To improve Liberty startup time by limiting CDI scanning

Two approaches:

### 1. If you wish to use CDI in some applications, but not in others

Tell CDI to only scan applications that contain a **beans.xml** file.  Disable "implicit" bean archives in Liberty by including this in your server config (*server.xml*)

`<cdi12 enableImplicitBeanArchives="false"/>`

See [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/cwlp_cdi_behavior.html) for a bit more discussion.

### 2. If you don't wish to use CDI at all, remove the CDI feature from the server config.

As Brett Kail pointed out, if this is the only application in the server and/or you don't want or need CDI at all, you can remove the `cdi-1.2` feature altogether from the `<featureManager>`.   As he also pointed out, be aware of features like `webProfile-7.0` or `javaee-7.0` which include the `cdi-1.2` feature.

Comment: Do you know if there is a setting for cdi-2.0 for `<cdi12 enableImplicitBeanArchives="false"/>` or has the default behavior been changed?

Comment: The doc: https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/reference/config/cdi12.html  suggests the same config element should work for 2.0.  Have you tried it?

Comment: I finally tried it and it works. Thank you.